# Find data for each subsequent financial period year in mdx query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

```
In my database cube, data is distributed like this, for each quarter, per year

2005 - > Q1 ->  10   2006 - > Q1 -> 4      2007 -> Q1-> 4
         Q2 ->  20            Q2 -> 4              Q2-> 44
         Q3 ->  5             Q3 -> 4              Q3-> 3
         Q4 ->  4             Q4 -> 4              Q4-> 3
```

For financial year 2006 & 2007 i need to fetch data from

```
2005 -> Q2,Q3,Q4 & Q1 of 2006 ie, 20, 5,4,4

2006 -> Q2,Q3,Q4 & Q1 of 2007 ie, 4,4,4,4
```

I have build mdx query like this - :

```
WITH MEMBER [LTII_NIRS_E] AS    
SUM({[DIM TIME].[YEAR -  QUARTER -  MONTH].[YEAR].[2005].[Q2]:[DIM TIME].[YEAR -      QUARTER -  MONTH].[YEAR].[2006].[Q1]},[Measures].[Measures].[LTII NIRS E])    

SELECT [LTII_NIRS_E]                                        ON COLUMNS,  {[DIM TIME].[YEAR - 
QUARTER -  MONTH].[2006]:[DIM TIME].[YEAR -  QUARTER -  MONTH].[2008]}
On ROWS FROM [NH_INCID]   WHERE [Business Component].[Region].[Novelis North America]
```

But it gives data only for 2005 financial year

ie, result look like this after executing query

```
2006 -> 33
2007- > 33  -> it should give 16 instead of 33
```

What should i write in SUM function in above query so that it calculates for each individual fiscal year.Please help me with this query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used lag to say give me the three quarters before the first quarter of the specified year member of the dim time hierarchy through the first quarter. This works because I use currentmember in the calculated member and then specify the members on the rows axis.

```
 WITH MEMBER [LTII_NIRS_E] AS
'Sum({[DIM TIME].[YEAR - QUARTER - MONTH].currentmember.firstchild.lag(3): [DIM TIME].[YEAR - QUARTER - MONTH].currentmember.firstchild}, [Measures].[LTII NIRS E])'
SELECT [LTII_NIRS_E] ON COLUMNS, 
{ [DIM TIME].[YEAR - QUARTER - MONTH].[2006], [DIM TIME].[YEAR - QUARTER - MONTH].[2007], [DIM TIME].[YEAR - QUARTER - MONTH].[2008]} on ROWS
 FROM [NH_INCID]
 WHERE [Business Component].[Region].[Novelis North America]
```