# Get specific period of each year in mdx query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

If I run this query

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[EMPLOYEE Recordable Case Rate] ON COLUMNS,
[DIM TIME].[YEAR -  QUARTER -  MONTH].[2006].[Q1]:  [DIM TIME].[YEAR -  QUARTER -  MONTH].[2010].[Q1] on ROWS

FROM
[NH_INCID]  
WHERE {[Business Component].[Region].[Novelis North America]}
```

It gives records starting from 2006 Q1, 2006 q2,2006 Q3, 2006 Q4------2010

**Is there any way to fetch only Q1 of each year ie, of 2006,2007,2008,2009,2010 ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the quarter dimension attribute to filter just Q1 and put a filter on the year span you want in the where clause.

```
Select {[Measures].[EMPLOYEE Recordable Case Rate]} ON COLUMNS, 
{[DIM TIME].[YEAR - QUARTER - MONTH].[Quarter].members } on 1
from [Model] 
where ({ [Dim Time].[Year].[2006]:[Dim Time].[Year].[2012]}, [Dim Time].[Quarter].[Q1])
```

You could also probably figure out a way to get the year and do something with firstchild, but my answer above seemed quicker/easier.

Comment: Hey marie, thanks for your answer, your answer is correct absolutely, Can you look into this link and help me, i am stuck for 3 days http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569637/find-data-for-each-subsequent-financial-period-year-in-mdx-query

Comment: From above query i want to calculate fiscal year, for fiscal year 2006, i have to take data of 2005's Q2,Q3,Q4 and 2006 Q1 and add them, for 2007 fiscal year i have to take data of 2006's Q2,Q3,Q4 and 2007 Q1 and add them and same upto year fiscal year 2013. please please help me in building the query